# Why does not Google Play Games in Unity work properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have these files in Assets/plugins/Android:

[image: Files]

Are these files correct?

When I click my button `Ranking` I see how my phone loads the Google Play Games screen (typical green screen).
But I can't login with my account and I can't see the leaderboard.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
public class BotonRanking : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    clickar();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void clickar() {
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI ("APICODE");
    } else {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {  });
    }
}
```

}

**The other Script:**

```
//SEND TO GOOGLE PLAY GAMES MY SCORE
        Social.ReportScore(contador, "APICODE", (bool success) => {});
```

Comment: Did you call PlayGamesPlatform.Activate(); in your app?? have you "Paste the game resources into the plugin setup dialog"?

Comment: yes, but now , I execute my App in Samsung galaxy mini and I can see the leaderboard but in my Huawei p7 I can`t... why? I updated google play games in both mobiles and the same account.

Comment: Ok, I solutionated my problem, thanks.